# Django file upload with UpdateView

Tags: django, file-upload, django-generic-views

I tried a minimalistic django implementation of generic views to upload profile pictures.

views.py

```
class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    form_class = UpdateUserProfileForm
    model = UserProfile
    success_url = reverse_lazy('show_profile')
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/img/%Y-%m-%d/', blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateUserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['website','picture']
```

userprofile_form.html

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Save" %}"/>
</form>
```

Everything works fine. Now error message. The website field will be updated properly, and a search button allows to choose a file for upload. However the file never appears in the system and the database field remains empty.

Unfortunately the django documentation on file upload (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/) does not include generic views, so I wonder if it is possible at all.

**Update:** Thanks to Alasdair's answer I updated my template so it works fine now as a minimalistic prototype for picture upload with generic views.

To display the picture, instructions of the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) are quite helpful again.

Also the media settings are necessary to upload the files to the media folder.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'absolute-path-to/media'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template

```
{% if userprofile.picture.url|length > 0 %}
    <img src="{{ userprofile.picture.url }}" width="200px">
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static "/img/default_profile.jpg" %}" width="200px" />
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem is in your template. You haven't set `enctype`, so `request.FILES` will always be empty. It should be:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```